# C++: how to track a pointer to a STL list element?

Tags: c++, stl

I would like to track a pointer to a list element for the next read access. This pointer would be advanced every time the list is read. Would it be bad practice to cache an iterator to the list as a member variable, assuming I take proper precautions when deleting list elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An iterator to a list element remains valid until the element it refers to is removed. This is guaranteed by the standard.

There is no problem with caching an iterator as long as you make sure you don't remove elements from the list or refresh the cached iterator when you do.

Comment: Not lists, the behaviour you describe is for vector iterators. List iterators are guaranteed to remain valid as long as the specific item they point to is not removed.

Comment: Invalidation due to reallocation is an issue for `std::vector`, but not for `std::list`, right?? The iterators for `std::list` will remain valid unless the item is erased from the list.

Comment: Ah crap, you're right. Thanks! Somehow I replaced list with vector in my mind. Fixed!

Answer (score 3):

Iterators are meant to be used. They aren't just for looping over each element in a for-loop. All you have to take into account is the rules for iterator invalidation.

`std::vector` iterators can be invalidated by any operation that inserts elements into the list. The iterators for all elements beyond the point of insertion are invalidated, and all iterators are invalidated if the insertion operation causes an increase in capacity. An operation that removes an element from the vector will invalidate any iterator after the point of removal.

`std::deque` iterators are invalidated by any operation that adds or removes elements from anywhere in the deque. So it's probably not a good idea to keep these around very long.

`std::list`, `std::set`, and `std::map` iterators are only invalidated by the specific removal of the particular element that the iterator refers to. These are the longest-lived of the iterator types.

As long as you keep these rules in mind, feel free to store these iterators all you want. It certainly isn't bad form to store `std::list` iterators, as long as you can be sure that that particular element isn't going anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you're going to be able to properly advance though an STL `std::list<T>` in a platform and compiler independent way is through the use of a `std::list<T>::iterator` or `std::list<T>::const_iterator`, so that's really your only option unless you're planning on implementing your own linked-list.  Per the standard, as others here have posted, an iterator to a `std::list` element will remain valid until that element is removed from the list.